# serviceaccount "grafana" not found

Tags: azure, kubernetes, azure-aks, kubernetes-pod

Getting the error

```
pods "grafana-5d64697748-" is forbidden: error looking up service
        account project-dev-monitoring/grafana: serviceaccount "grafana" not found
```

Where should I look for the service account in portal.azure.com which is missing?

Here is the full status

```
          kind: Deployment
apiVersion: apps/v1
metadata:
  name: grafana
  namespace: project-dev-monitoring
  uid: 333e3359-6fcb-4cca-b53b-c18bf759c21e
  resourceVersion: '781248'
  generation: 1
  creationTimestamp: '2022-05-13T14:10:18Z'
  labels:
    app: grafana
    app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: Helm
    chart: grafana-3.7.3
    heritage: Helm
    release: grafana
  annotations:
    deployment.kubernetes.io/revision: '1'
  managedFields:
    - manager: Mozilla
      operation: Update
      apiVersion: apps/v1
      time: '2022-05-13T14:10:18Z'
      fieldsType: FieldsV1
      fieldsV1:
        f:metadata:
          f:labels:
            .: {}
            f:app: {}
            f:app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: {}
            f:chart: {}
            f:heritage: {}
            f:release: {}
        f:spec:
          f:progressDeadlineSeconds: {}
          f:replicas: {}
          f:revisionHistoryLimit: {}
          f:selector: {}
          f:strategy:
            f:rollingUpdate:
              .: {}
              f:maxSurge: {}
              f:maxUnavailable: {}
            f:type: {}
          f:template:
            f:metadata:
              f:annotations:
                .: {}
                f:checksum/config: {}
                f:checksum/dashboards-json-config: {}
                f:checksum/sc-dashboard-provider-config: {}
                f:checksum/secret: {}
              f:labels:
                .: {}
                f:app: {}
                f:release: {}
            f:spec:
              f:containers:
                k:{"name":"grafana"}:
                  .: {}
                  f:env:
                    .: {}
                    k:{"name":"GF_ADMIN_PASSWORD"}:
                      .: {}
                      f:name: {}
                      f:valueFrom:
                        .: {}
                        f:secretKeyRef: {}
                    k:{"name":"GF_ADMIN_USER"}:
                      .: {}
                      f:name: {}
                      f:valueFrom:
                        .: {}
                        f:secretKeyRef: {}
                    k:{"name":"NO_PROXY"}:
                      .: {}
                      f:name: {}
                      f:value: {}
                  f:image: {}
                  f:imagePullPolicy: {}
                  f:livenessProbe:
                    .: {}
                    f:failureThreshold: {}
                    f:httpGet:
                      .: {}
                      f:path: {}
                      f:port: {}
                      f:scheme: {}
                    f:initialDelaySeconds: {}
                    f:periodSeconds: {}
                    f:successThreshold: {}
                    f:timeoutSeconds: {}
                  f:name: {}
                  f:ports:
                    .: {}
                    k:{"containerPort":80,"protocol":"TCP"}:
                      .: {}
                      f:containerPort: {}
                      f:name: {}
                      f:protocol: {}
                    k:{"containerPort":3000,"protocol":"TCP"}:
                      .: {}
                      f:containerPort: {}
                      f:name: {}
                      f:protocol: {}
                  f:readinessProbe:
                    .: {}
                    f:failureThreshold: {}
                    f:httpGet:
                      .: {}
                      f:path: {}
                      f:port: {}
                      f:scheme: {}
                    f:periodSeconds: {}
                    f:successThreshold: {}
                    f:timeoutSeconds: {}
                  f:resources: {}
                  f:terminationMessagePath: {}
                  f:terminationMessagePolicy: {}
                  f:volumeMounts:
                    .: {}
                    k:{"mountPath":"/etc/grafana/grafana.ini"}:
                      .: {}
                      f:mountPath: {}
                      f:name: {}
                      f:subPath: {}
                    k:{"mountPath":"/etc/grafana/ldap.toml"}:
                      .: {}
                      f:mountPath: {}
                      f:name: {}
                      f:subPath: {}
                    k:{"mountPath":"/etc/grafana/provisioning/dashboards/dashboardproviders.yaml"}:
                      .: {}
                      f:mountPath: {}
                      f:name: {}
                      f:subPath: {}
                    k:{"mountPath":"/etc/grafana/provisioning/datasources/datasources.yaml"}:
                      .: {}
                      f:mountPath: {}
                      f:name: {}
                      f:subPath: {}
                    k:{"mountPath":"/var/lib/grafana"}:
                      .: {}
                      f:mountPath: {}
                      f:name: {}
                    k:{"mountPath":"/var/lib/grafana/dashboards/cluster"}:
                      .: {}
                      f:mountPath: {}
                      f:name: {}
                    k:{"mountPath":"/var/lib/grafana/dashboards/jaeger"}:
                      .: {}
                      f:mountPath: {}
                      f:name: {}
                    k:{"mountPath":"/var/lib/grafana/dashboards/microservice"}:
                      .: {}
                      f:mountPath: {}
                      f:name: {}
                    k:{"mountPath":"/var/lib/grafana/dashboards/namespace"}:
                      .: {}
                      f:mountPath: {}
                      f:name: {}
                    k:{"mountPath":"/var/lib/grafana/dashboards/pod"}:
                      .: {}
                      f:mountPath: {}
                      f:name: {}
              f:dnsPolicy: {}
              f:imagePullSecrets:
                .: {}
                k:{"name":"registry-secret"}: {}
              f:restartPolicy: {}
              f:schedulerName: {}
              f:securityContext: {}
              f:serviceAccount: {}
              f:serviceAccountName: {}
              f:terminationGracePeriodSeconds: {}
              f:volumes:
                .: {}
                k:{"name":"config"}:
                  .: {}
                  f:configMap:
                    .: {}
                    f:defaultMode: {}
                    f:name: {}
                  f:name: {}
                k:{"name":"dashboards-cluster"}:
                  .: {}
                  f:configMap:
                    .: {}
                    f:defaultMode: {}
                    f:name: {}
                  f:name: {}
                k:{"name":"dashboards-jaeger"}:
                  .: {}
                  f:configMap:
                    .: {}
                    f:defaultMode: {}
                    f:name: {}
                  f:name: {}
                k:{"name":"dashboards-microservice"}:
                  .: {}
                  f:configMap:
                    .: {}
                    f:defaultMode: {}
                    f:name: {}
                  f:name: {}
                k:{"name":"dashboards-namespace"}:
                  .: {}
                  f:configMap:
                    .: {}
                    f:defaultMode: {}
                    f:name: {}
                  f:name: {}
                k:{"name":"dashboards-pod"}:
                  .: {}
                  f:configMap:
                    .: {}
                    f:defaultMode: {}
                    f:name: {}
                  f:name: {}
                k:{"name":"ldap"}:
                  .: {}
                  f:name: {}
                  f:secret:
                    .: {}
                    f:defaultMode: {}
                    f:items: {}
                    f:secretName: {}
                k:{"name":"storage"}:
                  .: {}
                  f:emptyDir: {}
                  f:name: {}
    - manager: kube-controller-manager
      operation: Update
      apiVersion: apps/v1
      time: '2022-05-13T14:10:19Z'
      fieldsType: FieldsV1
      fieldsV1:
        f:metadata:
          f:annotations:
            .: {}
            f:deployment.kubernetes.io/revision: {}
        f:status:
          f:conditions:
            .: {}
            k:{"type":"Available"}:
              .: {}
              f:lastTransitionTime: {}
              f:lastUpdateTime: {}
              f:message: {}
              f:reason: {}
              f:status: {}
              f:type: {}
            k:{"type":"Progressing"}:
              .: {}
              f:lastTransitionTime: {}
              f:lastUpdateTime: {}
              f:message: {}
              f:reason: {}
              f:status: {}
              f:type: {}
            k:{"type":"ReplicaFailure"}:
              .: {}
              f:lastTransitionTime: {}
              f:lastUpdateTime: {}
              f:message: {}
              f:reason: {}
              f:status: {}
              f:type: {}
          f:observedGeneration: {}
          f:unavailableReplicas: {}
      subresource: status
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: grafana
      release: grafana
  template:
    metadata:
      creationTimestamp: null
      labels:
        app: grafana
        release: grafana
      annotations:
        checksum/config: 57c643240b47b68526b116c81e3a3f17e25e904922427809b7c18d04ee08b0
        checksum/dashboards-json-config: 01ba4719c80b6fe911b091a7c124b64eeece964e09c058ef8f9805daca546b
        checksum/sc-dashboard-provider-config: 01ba4719c80b6fe911b091a7c051b64eeece964e09c058ef8f9805daca546b
        checksum/secret: 82a0f11824a8b39fadedeffd364353f3b8cbdac40f8d02805b3fc7a134f07
    spec:
      volumes:
        - name: config
          configMap:
            name: grafana
            defaultMode: 420
        - name: dashboards-cluster
          configMap:
            name: cluster-statistics
            defaultMode: 420
        - name: dashboards-jaeger
          configMap:
            name: jaeger-statistics
            defaultMode: 420
        - name: dashboards-microservice
          configMap:
            name: spring-boot-statistics
            defaultMode: 420
        - name: dashboards-namespace
          configMap:
            name: namespace-statistics
            defaultMode: 420
        - name: dashboards-pod
          configMap:
            name: pod-statistics
            defaultMode: 420
        - name: ldap
          secret:
            secretName: grafana
            items:
              - key: ldap-toml
                path: ldap.toml
            defaultMode: 420
        - name: storage
          emptyDir: {}
      containers:
        - name: grafana
          image: projectaksacr.azurecr.io/ims-project/grafana:8.1.2
          ports:
            - name: service
              containerPort: 80
              protocol: TCP
            - name: grafana
              containerPort: 3000
              protocol: TCP
          env:
            - name: GF__ADMIN_USER
              valueFrom:
                secretKeyRef:
                  name: grafana
                  key: adm-user
            - name: GF__ADMIN_PASSWORD
              valueFrom:
                secretKeyRef:
                  name: grafana
                  key: admin-password
            - name: NO_PROXY
              value: >-
                .apps.cloud.cloud.local,.svc.cluster.local,localhost,127.0.0.1
          resources: {}
          volumeMounts:
            - name: config
              mountPath: /etc/grafana/grafana.ini
              subPath: grafana.ini
            - name: ldap
              mountPath: /etc/grafana/ldap.toml
              subPath: ldap.toml
            - name: storage
              mountPath: /var/lib/grafana
            - name: dashboards-namespace
              mountPath: /var/lib/grafana/dashboards/namespace
            - name: dashboards-pod
              mountPath: /var/lib/grafana/dashboards/pod
            - name: dashboards-cluster
              mountPath: /var/lib/grafana/dashboards/cluster
            - name: dashboards-jaeger
              mountPath: /var/lib/grafana/dashboards/jaeger
            - name: dashboards-microservice
              mountPath: /var/lib/grafana/dashboards/microservice
            - name: config
              mountPath: /etc/grafana/provisioning/datasources/datasources.yaml
              subPath: datasources.yaml
            - name: config
              mountPath: /etc/grafana/provisioning/dashboards/dashboardproviders.yaml
              subPath: dashboardproviders.yaml
          livenessProbe:
            httpGet:
              path: /api/health
              port: 3000
              scheme: HTTP
            initialDelaySeconds: 60
            timeoutSeconds: 30
            periodSeconds: 10
            successThreshold: 1
            failureThreshold: 10
          readinessProbe:
            httpGet:
              path: /api/health
              port: 3000
              scheme: HTTP
            timeoutSeconds: 1
            periodSeconds: 10
            successThreshold: 1
            failureThreshold: 3
          terminationMessagePath: /dev/termination-log
          terminationMessagePolicy: File
          imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
      restartPolicy: Always
      terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 30
      dnsPolicy: ClusterFirst
      serviceAccountName: grafana
      serviceAccount: grafana
      securityContext: {}
      imagePullSecrets:
        - name: registry-secret
      schedulerName: default-scheduler
  strategy:
    type: RollingUpdate
    rollingUpdate:
      maxUnavailable: 25%
      maxSurge: 25%
  revisionHistoryLimit: 10
  progressDeadlineSeconds: 600
status:
  observedGeneration: 1
  unavailableReplicas: 1
  conditions:
    - type: Available
      status: 'False'
      lastUpdateTime: '2022-05-13T14:10:19Z'
      lastTransitionTime: '2022-05-13T14:10:19Z'
      reason: MinimumReplicasUnavailable
      message: Deployment does not have minimum availability.
    - type: ReplicaFailure
      status: 'True'
      lastUpdateTime: '2022-05-13T14:10:19Z'
      lastTransitionTime: '2022-05-13T14:10:19Z'
      reason: FailedCreate
      message: >-
        pods "grafana-5d64697748-" is forbidden: error looking up service
        account project-dev-monitoring/grafana: serviceaccount "grafana" not found
    - type: Progressing
      status: 'False'
      lastUpdateTime: '2022-05-13T14:20:19Z'
      lastTransitionTime: '2022-05-13T14:20:19Z'
      reason: ProgressDeadlineExceeded
      message: ReplicaSet "grafana-5d64697748" has timed out progressing.
```

Comment: How did you deploy Grafana? Do you have this error when installing?

Comment: i am just moving deployments from ocp to aks, i have a deployment yaml i just copy and deployed it in aks

Comment: looks like secrets are missing? or where should I need to check for service accounts in the azure portal to see grafana service account exists.

Comment: The deployment yaml is only a portion of the workload. Most likely there was also a SA definition and a service definition as well. I recommend https://github.com/prometheus-operator/kube-prometheus for setting up prometheus and grafana on k8s.

Comment: dnsPolicy: ClusterFirst
      serviceAccountName: grafana
      serviceAccount: grafana
      securityContext: {}
      imagePullSecrets:
        - name: registry-secret
      schedulerName: default-scheduler

Comment: its there , details are mentioned about service account, i also updated it, but i am unable to find where exactly this service account configured

Comment: You are getting this error when you do what??? Where is your manifest? How are you trying to deploy grafana? Are you using kubectl???? Please give more Infos !

Comment: Check this it may help you :https://github.com/grafana/kubernetes-app/issues/58

Comment: Please avoid having conversations in comments - that's not what comments are for. All details should be placed in your question, via editing your question.